# Обработка новых строк в файле

Tags: bash

Здравствуйте. Вот начало задания

> Процесс «Генератор» передает информацию процессу «Обработчик» с помощью файла. Процесс
> «Обработчик» должен осуществлять следующую обработку новых строк в этом файле: если строка
> содержит единственный символ «+», то процесс обработчик...

Продолжение не важно. Вопрос в том, как обрабатывать новые строки.
Знаю, что для слежения за файлом есть команда tail с флагом -f, но не могу её запихнуть в свой скрипт. Пробовал вот так

```
while read s
do
echo $s
done < $(tail -f "file.txt")
```

не получилось, выводятся пустые строки. Ещё пробовал вот так

```
while true
do
read s < "file.txt"
echo $s
done
```

в бесконечном цикле выводит первую строчку. Как правильно организовать считывание новых строчек?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я тупой (( В примере задания написано, как его делать((

```
(tail -n 0 -f data.txt) |
while true; do
  read LINE;
  case $LINE in
    QUIT)
      echo "exit"
      killall tail
      exit
      ;;
    *)
      echo $LINE
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: Только вот `killall` как-то нехорошо...
(что произойдет, если вы несколько  задач, вызывающих `tail` одновременно запустили?)

М.б. лучше заменить его на

      kill `ps -ef | grep $$$$ | grep tail | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: Да, я понимаю, это учебный пример.